# Bug in random numbers in Android

Tags: java, android, math, random

```
TreeSet myNumbers = new TreeSet();
Random randGen = new Random();

for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    // number generation here
    int randNum = randGen.nextInt(16 - 1) + 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (myNumbers.add(randNum))
            break;
        else
            randNum = randGen.nextInt();

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + randNum, 100).show();
}
```

I want to generate random numbers between 1 and 16 and the same number should not be repeated.

The code above gives me output like:

```
2, 5, 7, 9, 1, 4, 10.4109446, -448831, 98824724, 11, 13, ...
```

I do not know why it gives me random numbers not in the 1-16 range, please help me out.

Comment: Your code appears to be giving you *non-integer* results, which suggests that maybe you're not really diagnosing it properly. I'd be surprised if you could really persuade Android to store 10.4109446 in an `int`.

Comment: You do make one `nextInt()` call. Without a parameter this will return numbers outside your range.

Comment: What the hell is this `for (;;) {`?!

Comment: @Vyger an infinite loop

Comment: @blackbelt: like `while(true) {`?

Comment: @blackbelt: thank you. I never finish learning something new.

Comment: @Vyger   
follow this link 

http://www.ehow.com/how_12112659_generate-random-numbers-repetition-java.html

Comment: OK, thank you for sharing - blackbelt, though, with just 2 words, already gave me a perfect answer... he's got the gift of synthesis! ;)

Comment: I think the '.' in the output is just a typo, and it was actually a ','. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

To generate a random number in a range, it is like:

```
int min = ...
int max = ...
int randNumber = min + new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1);
```

So in your example where you want to generate a random number from [1, 16], it would look like:

```
int randNumber = 1 + new Random().nextInt(16 - 1 + 1);
```

Or if you choose to simplify:

```
int randNumber = 1 + new Random().nextInt(16);
```

Also, you should really be using a `while` loop instead of an infinite `for` loop:

```
    final TreeSet<Integer> myNumbers = new TreeSet<>();
    final Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        int n = 1 + rand.nextInt(16);
        while(!myNumbers.add(n))
            n = 1 + rand.nextInt(16);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You're only generating *one* number in the range 1-15. You're then generating *subsequent* numbers with just `nextInt`:

```
if (myNumbers.add(randNum))
    break;
else
    randNum = randGen.nextInt();
```

That should be:

```
if (myNumbers.add(randNum))
    break;
else
    randNum = randGen.nextInt(16) + 1;
```

... and fix the initial call to `nextInt` to remove the "-1". (You don't need the `16 - 1`, as explained in Josh's answer.)

Comment: @VikrantAlekar if it solved your problem why dont you accept it

Answer (score 1):

It's not a big issue, if you are working in the range 1-16, but your code results in rejection of some randomly drawn numbers, if they have already been picked before.
In your solution, the expected value of `nextInt()` calls is proportional to *n log(n)*, where *n* is the number of total elements you want to shuffle (16 in your case) – and the actual values can be much higher for a single run. You might consider using a more efficient implementation.

A solution which always uses only *n* calls:

```
ArrayList<Integer> originalNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random randGen = new Random();
int max = 16;
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    // initializing ordered list so it becomes 1, 2, ..., max
    originalNumbers.add(i);
}
for (int i = max; i >= 1; i--) {
    // picking a random number from the ordered list, and swapping it
    // with the last unpicked element which is placed closer to the
    // end of list, where the already picked numbers are stored
    int randNum = randGen.nextInt(i);
    Collections.swap(originalNumbers, i - 1, randNum);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + originalNumbers[i - 1], 100).show();
}
```

Comment: Assume `TreeSet.add` to be _O(n log n)_, `HashSet.add` ~ _O(1)_, `Random.nextInt` ~ _O(1)_; and number of calls to `Set.add` to be _O(n log n)_ as you state. Then the complexity of the OP's method is _O((n log n) ^ 2)_. Using `HashSet` or `boolean[n]` gives us complexity _O(n log n)_. Your method (naïve Fisher-Yates shuffle) requires _O(n)_ time for each of _n_ calls to `ArrayList.remove` ‒ _O(n^2)_ total; worse than _O(n log n)_. The **Knuth shuffle**, where you swap the chosen element with the last one before removing, has complexity _O(n)_. Surprisingly, none of the answers here uses it.

Comment: You're not _swapping_ the elements

Comment: thanks again @kyrill, hope it's fine now. unfortunately I don't have any dev envs set up at the moment, coding quite blindly. let me know if it's still not ok.

Comment: `Collections.swap(originalNumbers, i - 1, randNum);` so you allow an element to stay in the same position