# Generate three different random numbers

Tags: python

I've got something here, but I can't get it working how I like it:

```
def nested_loops():
    import random
    option1 = random.randint(1, 3)
    option2 = random.randint(1, 3)
    option3 = random.randint(1, 3)
```

The bit above generates numbers, but they may be the same.
The below code this should fix that, but it doesn't, but it just seems to decrease the likelihood:

```
while option1 == option2:
    option1 = random.randint(1,3)
    while option1 == option3:
        option1 = random.randint(1, 3)
        while option2 == option3:
            option2 = random.randint(1, 3)

print(option1)
print(option2)
print(option3)
```

It is fairly obvious it just prints them.

Comment: Agree that based on the accepted answer this is a duplicate, but feel the need to point out that import random;alist = [x+1 for x in range(3)]; random.shuffle(alist) will handle the case where the list is 1 to N (in this case 3)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.sample) to get any amount of unique 'random' items from an iterable- there is no need to use nested loops:

```
>>> option1, option2, option3 = random.sample(range(1, 4), 3)
>>> option1, option2, option3
(3, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is that if `option1` and `option2` are different, the first `while` won't be entered, and you won't examine if any of them are equal to `option3`.

Comment: If you are looking for a rejection-free implementation, I suggest to check out my answer from yesterday in this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563558/bug-in-random-numbers-in-android/22571791#22571791 - I know it's in java, but you can get the idea.