# What does the random.sample() method in Python do?

Tags: python, random

I want to know the use of `random.sample()` method and what does it give? When should it be used and some example usage.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577916/using-nested-loops-to-generate-3-different-random-numbers/22577977#22577977

Answer (score 80, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample):

> random.sample(population, k)
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements
> chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without
> replacement.

Basically, it picks k unique random elements, a sample, from a sequence:

```
>>> import random
>>> c = list(range(0, 15))
>>> c
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> random.sample(c, 5)
[9, 2, 3, 14, 11]
```

`random.sample` works also directly from a range:

```
>>> c = range(0, 15)
>>> c
range(0, 15)
>>> random.sample(c, 5)
[12, 3, 6, 14, 10]
```

In versions earlier than 3.11, `random.sample` works with sets too:

```
>>> c = {1, 2, 4}
>>> random.sample(c, 2)
[4, 1]
```

However, `random.sample` doesn't work with arbitrary iterators:

```
>>> c = [1, 3]
>>> random.sample(iter(c), 5)
TypeError: Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).
```

In version 3.9, the `counts` parameter was added:

> Repeated elements can be specified one at a time or with the
> optional keyword-only counts parameter.
> For example, sample(['red', 'blue'], counts=[4, 2], k=5)
> is equivalent to
> sample(['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'], k=5).

Comment: so from a given sequence it will randomly choose a given no. of elements, right??

Comment: @kartikey_kant yup, that's it, it's simple.

Comment: how do we pass a column to random.sample() ? I am getting the above TypeError.

Answer (score 3):

`random.sample()` also works on text

example:

```
> text = open("textfile.txt").read() 

> random.sample(text, 5)

> ['f', 's', 'y', 'v', '\n']
```

**\n** is also seen as a character so that can also be returned

you could use `random.sample()` to return random words from a text file if you first use the split method

example:

```
> words = text.split()

> random.sample(words, 5)

> ['the', 'and', 'a', 'her', 'of']
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
your answer is well formatted and have meaning its better to read this instruction for better answering

Comment: your terminology is misleading- `text` here is a string, and `words` a list- `random.sample()` works on strings and lists because they are sequences

Answer (score 0):

```
random.sample(population, k)
```

It is used for randomly sampling a sample of length `'k'` from a population. returns a `'k'` length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set

it returns a new list and leaves the original population unchanged and the resulting list is in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples

I am putting up an example in which I am splitting a dataset randomly. It is basically a function in which you pass `x_train(population)` as an argument and return indices of `60%` of the data as `D_test`.

```
import random

def randomly_select_70_percent_of_data_from_1_to_length(x_train):
    return random.sample(range(0, len(x_train)), int(0.6*len(x_train)))
```

Answer (score -3):

```py
from random import *
lst1 = sample(range(0, 1000), 100)
lst2 = sample(range(0, 1000), 100)
print(lst1)
print(lst2)
print(set(lst1).intersection(set(lst2)))
```

Comment: This answer could _definitely_ use some supporting information. Please [edit] it to include descriptions of the code, and what it's doing. See [answer] for more information on posting good answers.