# random.sample in python implies choosing uniformly?

Tags: python, random

random.sample (population, k) in python means choosing uniformly and randomly from a population with distinct individuals k unique individuals, am I correct ? I never saw the uniform part. So, I guess it should be this way. Sorry if this is a duplicated as the following one. I initially put my concern there, but since I do not have enough poputation yet, someone flaged my answer. Anyway, any comments are greatly appreciated.

Related: [What does random.sample() method in python do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741319/what-does-random-sample-method-in-python-do/29077746?noredirect=1#comment46390795_29077746)

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Every item has an equal chance of being drawn out.