# I'm trying to make a simple script that says two different two phrase lines(Python)

Tags: python, random

So, I'm just starting to program Python and I wanted to make a very simple script that will say something like "Gabe- Hello, my name is Gabe (Just an example of a sentence" + "Jerry- Hello Gabe, I'm Jerry" OR "Gabe- Goodbye, Jerry" + "Jerry- Goodbye, Gabe". Here's pretty much what I wrote.

```
 answers1 = [
"James-Hello, my name is James!"
]
answers2 = [
    "Jerry-Hello James, my name is Jerry!"
    ]
answers3 = [
    "Gabe-Goodbye, Samuel."
        ]
 answers4 = [
    "Samuel-Goodbye, Gabe"
    ]
Jack1 = (answers1 + answers2)
Jack2 = (answers3 + answers4)
Jacks = ([Jack1,Jack2])
import random
for x in range(2):
    a = random.randint(0,2)
    print (random.sample([Jacks, a]))
```

I'm quite sure it's a very simple fix, but as I have just started Python (Like, literally 2-3 days ago) I don't quite know what the problem would be. Here's my error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Test Python 3.py", line 19, in <module>
print (random.sample([Jacks, a]))
TypeError: sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

If anyone could help me with this, I would very much appreciate it! Other than that, I shall be searching on ways that may be relevant to fixing this.

Comment: I posted this at 3:34 AM Central, so I'll see any comment that may appear later. But I will reply, unless it's completely unrelated, like "Whats your great great great grandmothers Maiden name?"

Comment: You've inserted a list as the argument to random.sample. Just use `random.sample(Jacks, a)`

Comment: Check [the doc for random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sample` requires a parameter `k` that indicates how many random samples you want to take. However in this case it looks like you do not need `sample`, since you already have the random integer. Note that that integer should be in the range `[0,1]`, because the list `Jack` has only two elements.

```
    a = random.randint(0,1)
    print (Jacks[a])
```

or the same behavior with `sample`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741319/what-does-random-sample-method-in-python-do) for an explanation.

```
   print (random.sample(Jacks,1))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
random.sample([Jacks, a])
```

This [sample](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.sample) method should looks like

```
random.sample(Jacks, a)
```

However, I am concerted you also have no idea how lists are working. Can you explain why do you using lists of strings and then adding values in them? I am losing you here.

If you going to pick a pair or strings, use method described by Florian (requesting data by `index` value.)

Answer (score -2):

k parameter tell random.sample function that how many sample you need, you should write:

```
 print (random.sample([Jacks, a], 3))
```

which means you need 3 sample from your list. the output will be something like:

```
[1, jacks, 0]
```