# How can I generate list of random odd numbers from 1 to 99 (including) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am using the following code:-

```
my_list = range(1,99) 
list_Odd_Numbers = list(filter(lambda varX: varX % 2 == 1,my_list)) 
print(list_Odd_Numbers)
```

I want random and infinite loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does random.sample() method in python do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741319/what-does-random-sample-method-in-python-do)

Comment: What does this have to do with xcode? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

random_odd_numbers = (val for val in iter(lambda: randint(1, 99), 0) if val % 2 != 0)

for number in random_odd_numbers:
    print(number)
```

Prints:

```
...
99
81
57
85
87
95
49
...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import random and then:

```
import random

my_list = range(1,99) 
list_Odd_Numbers = list(filter(lambda varX: varX % 2 == 1,my_list))
while True: # Not recommended, but since you asked for infinite loop...
    x = random.choice(list_Odd_Numbers) # Pick randomly one number from the list.
    print(x) # or do whatever you need to with this random pick.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution, don't need to filter anything

```
2*random.randint(0,49)+1
```

If you need 100 numbers in a list

```
[2*random.randint(0,49)+1 for _ in range(0,100)]
```

UPDATE

Actually, there is a function in standard Python which does the job

```
random.randrange(1, 100, 2)
```