# what code is more efficient for me to write if i want to be sure that in no way the random choices in my code gets repeated?

Tags: python, random

so here is the code

```
import random
choices = [1,2,3,4,5]
choice1=random.choice(choices)
choice2=random.choice(choices)
if choice1==choice2 :
    choice2 =random.choice(choices)
```

so from my knowledge, this code works for one time (like what if the second time also the choice got as same ) and if i want to use while , i cant say (while choice1 != choice2)cause in the order of code they should be before defined so what is your solution (also if you feel explaining in more detail problems to level of my conceptualization it would be very appreciated )

Comment: Python provides you a readymade way of doing this: `choice1, choice2 = random.sample(choices, k=2)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741319/what-does-the-random-sample-method-in-python-do

Comment: @slothrop or anybody would explain this code more?

Comment: I added a link to another StackOverflow question where the answers explain it in detail.

Comment: See `random.sample` here in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Note: If choices is a sequence of the same value, e.g. `choices = [1,1,1,1,1]`, then `choices1` will always equal `choices2`. In general, even with a sequence of distinct values, it's possible (with rapidly decreasing probability) for the random choice to be the same one over and over again.

Comment: @President James K. Polk so you want to say actually the sample function would not work ?or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also try with a while, to keep generating a new random number for choice2 until is different from choice1

```
import random
choices = [1,2,3,4,5]
choice1=random.choice(choices)
choice2=random.choice(choices)
while choice1==choice2 :
    choice2 =random.choice(choices)
```

Comment: I still think `random.sample` or even taking the first two elements from the result of `random.shuffle` is a better idea.