# How can I replace a integer that shows up twice in a random list

Tags: python, list, random, integer

I have a list that looks like this:

```
l = [random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9),random.randint(0,9)]
```

but if it outputs something like this`[9,0,5,5]` what can I do replace the repeating integer?

Comment: `set(l)` .............

Comment: Also related [generate 3 different random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577916/generate-3-different-random-numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to get four unique items in random order, let Python do the work for you:

```
l = random.sample(range(10), 4)
```

[`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) is intended specifically for "random sampling without replacement", which appears to be the goal of your code.

Comment: I do need the numbers in a list is this possible

Comment: @SafeG: `random.sample` returns a `list` already. Example from my local computer: `>>> random.sample(range(10), 4)` output: `[0, 5, 7, 6]`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I have been looking for days at this!