# How can i get multiple different random numbers at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pong

I wanna make a pong game with two balls, so I need two random numbers for the initial direction of each ball. As far as I know python uses the hour as seed, so as long as both numbers are asked in a same time (just some ms later that don't affect at all), both random numbers will be the same. How can I get two different random numbers at the same time?

I tried to get to different random numbers but both numbers were the same. Therefore, both balls took the same direction.

Comment: Please provide the code, how you "get to different random numbers but both numbers were the same"

Comment: You need to provide code because your description makes no sense: if you ask the RNG for two numbers it will return the first one, advance the internal state, then return the second one so you should not get the same value twice (except in the sense that it's perfectly acceptable for an RNG to randomly return the same value twice). And Python does *not* generally use the system time as seed, it uses the OS's randomness source, and only falls back to time if that's not available: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a18c9854e8c255981f07c0a1c1503253f85b7540/Modules/_randommodule.c#L301-L312

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your code, the reason for the duplicate numbers could be many reasons. The module does not utilize hours as the only timestamp, but also some higher precisions, see the following example:

```
import random

a = random.random()
b = random.random()
print(a, b)
```

0.5273803990480128 0.16814494622242826

However, one can ensure that the same same number gets produced if a new seed is called again and again:

```
import random

for i in range(3):
    random.seed(1)
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(num)
```

18
18
18

Specifically for your game, you should only call a seed once (in cases where you want reproducibility). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577916/generate-three-different-random-numbers) also summarizes the answer to your question.

Note: This is my first time answering questions so feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Feedback: Generally, a good answer in that the thoughts are  well explained and proper grammar and formatting are used.  Conversely, it’s premature as we don’t yet understand the problem, due to a vague question.  Therefore, the *completeness* of the answer cannot be determined.  (Upvote for your thought process and effort.)